# How to "map" model values to select box when editing forms in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fetching data with a query in my AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.customers = xAccount.query();
```

and I am using a select box to show a dropdown item with customer data:

```
<select type="text"
    data-ng-model="mymodel.customer_id"
    data-ng-options="customer.id as customer.name for customer in customers track by customer.id">
</select>
```

The data that the `$scope.customers` shows are like this:

```
[
    {"id":"12345678","name":"first customer"},
    {"id":"23456789","name":"second customer"},
    {"id":"34567890","name":"third customer"}
]
```

The $scope model I am using is:

```
mymodel.customer_id
```

Right now I am able to get all the customers by API call, show their names as select labels and ids as select values and then save the selected one to the database as `select.value = mymodel.customer_id`. This works fine.

What doesn't work is the "edit" view/form. When the edit form (which is the same as the "new" form) is displayed, the select box fetched value is empty. This means that the `mymodel.customer_id` is set (I can view it as a string like "12345678" in the firebug's JSON display) but it isn't "attached" to the `select.value` of the form. How can I achieve that?

I tried to use `data-ng-init="mymodel.customer_id = (customers | filter:{id: mymodel.customer_id})[0].name"` but of course it fails.

Comment: `customer.id as customer.name` -> i do not think you got it right

Comment: @Atais anything to suggest ?

Comment: see a colon between 3rd item in customers

Comment: @Selva sorry fixed that

Comment: @Radolino would you make a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: @Atais the project is huge and I can't think of a way to replicate the functionality in a plunker

Comment: don't use track by when you use `**customer.id** as customer.name for customer in customers` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I am getting a `message Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. ` If I do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the similar issue before and what I had done to fix is to populate the `$scope.customers` first and then populate the value in `mymodel.customer_id`.

So basically, you have to first pull all your customers via `$scope.customers = xAccount.query();` when you open your edit form and then you can use the promise success callback of that to pull your customer detail.

I didn't get time to dig into the problem, but that worked for me.

Considering `xAccount` is an instance of `$resource` with GET request:

```
$scope.editCustomer = function() {     // Or whatever is your function when your edit form opens

    // First get all the customers
    $scope.customers = xAccount.query(null, function() {
        // When you successfully get your customer data (success callback)
        // Now here you have to make another call to get your customer
        $scope.mymodel = MyModel.get({id: $routeParams.id});
    });
};
```

Now, what I'm trying to say is that, when you open your edit form (I'm considering `editCustomer()` method is invoked which is first getting all customers data. After customer data received from the server (and binded to the `select` in the HTML), then only we are getting the data for the customer being edited using the `MyModel`.

Comment: I am not sure I got what you wrote. How could using promises help ?

Comment: Sure, what is your `xAccount`? Is it an instance of `$resource`?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simple example. Please check it out and let me know if you understand it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what does it have to do with my issue. Why are you using get and use a nested call for a standard user ?

Comment: Can you please provide a plunkr or fiddle? Or can you please show some code that how are you getting the custom detail value in `$scope.mymodel.customer_id`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a big application and it will take several hours to create a plunkr that it's working

Comment: Okay. Did that thing worked for you? If not then can you please tell me that how you are getting the value in `$scope.mymodel.customer_id`?

Comment: With another model $scope.mymodel = MyModel.get({id: $routeParams.id}); in the same controller. So $scope.mymodel.customer_id should be equal to an object.id in $scope.customers. I show the "new/edit" form and one of the form's model attrs is "customer_id". Then I query a customers instance and get ids/names. The data from xAccount.query () are displayed on the forms. Strangely, the new form works fine, but the edit form which retrieves the data, fails and displays a blank/empty value.

Comment: Okay :-) Another attempt to explain. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it doesn't seem to work. The id/name of the xAccount isn't yet mapped to the $scope.mymodel.customer_id, so empty is displayed. Also, I don't find it pretty to call the MyModel entity from inside all other ones.

Comment: If I don't map the "id" to the select box "value", everything will fail as I find it impossible for them to map magically. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the angular docs about [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> This will work:
>
> ```
> <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select> 
> $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
> ```
>
> but this will not work:
>
> ```
> <select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
> ```
>
> ```
>  $scope.selected = $scope.items[0].subItem;
> ```
>
> In both examples, the track by expression is
>   applied successfully to each item in the items array. Because the
>   selected option has been set programmatically in the controller, the
>   track by expression is also applied to the ngModel value. In the first
>   example, the ngModel value is items[0] and the track by expression
>   evaluates to items[0].id with no issue. In the second example, the
>   ngModel value is items[0].subItem and the track by expression
>   evaluates to items[0].subItem.id (which is undefined). As a result,
>   the model value is not matched against any `<option>` and the `<select>`
>   appears as having no selected value.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNEUFrX1Loc7By70d3hi?p=preview).
I cannot however recreate your duplicate scenario.

Comment: But the issue is that the current item is not selected automatically when editing the model's data by the form. You actually hardcode the selected as the first of the items.

Comment: I just pointed out why this is happening. Because if you have as value `customer.id` and use`track by customer.id` the `ngModel` value is `customer.id`and track by evaluates to `customers.id.id` so it appears as having no selected value. You can solve this by `ng-repeat`options manually as you have already or by eliminating duplicates before hand. Hope that clarified some things

Comment: Starting to make sense. What do you mean "eliminating duplicates before hand" ?

Comment: You said that you have duplicate values can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I spent several hours to figure this out. The ng-options hit me hard. I generated the values by customer.id as.... track by customer.id", so by trying everything out, I saw in the value field of select something strange, like `value="string:32445454"`. At first sight something seemed wrong to me but not enough to stay and fix it. Finally, I tried to remove "track by" section in ng-options and something happened. The right select option was auto-selected but when PUT to the API, I got a message that a field cannot be repeated ...

I checked the value again and saw that the same value was outputting to this field. So I tried to take it manually and set `<option ng-repeat="customer in customers" value="{{ customer.id }}">{{ customer.name }}</option>` ...guess what? It worked fine.

```
<select type="text" data-ng-model="mymodel.customer_name">
    <option ng-repeat="customer in customers"
            value="{{ customer.id }}">
            {{ customer.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the Options**

```
  $scope.statusTypeOption=['Activate','Inactivate'];
```

**Now on UI**

```
 <select id="status" class="form-control" ng-init="status" ng-model="status" ng-options="option for option in statusTypeOption"></select>
```

**And in Controller**

```
 $scope.status=(response.lCode.status=='A'?'Activate':'Inactivate');
```